# APEX - Compare value against current user ID

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle-apex

I'm attempting to create a report that will present filtered information depending on the user ID. Lecturers will be able to login to the system and will see all of the modules that they are the leader of, the login ID is the same as the lecturer code that is used to define lecturer code in the module table.

Here is my SQL query.

```
SELECT m.module_code, m.module_name, m.lecturer_code, 
m.module_number_assessments, m.module_moderator FROM module m, lecturer l 
WHERE m.lecturer_code = [Select l.lecturer_code from lecturer l where 
l.lecturer_code = UserInfo.getUserId()];
```

I receive the following error "Query cannot be parsed, please check the syntax of your query. (ORA-00936: missing expression)" when attempting to use this as the source for the report.

I am fairly new to APEX. Any ideas why this code is invalid?

Comment: Please learn to use proper explicit `join` syntax.

Comment: Thanks, but I received the error: Query cannot be parsed, please check the syntax of your query. (ORA-00904: "USERINFO"."GETUSERID": invalid identifier)

Comment: That means that the underlying database doesn't understand the function you are using.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I assumed this was the explicit join syntax. Could you post an amended version, so I can see where I have went wrong?

Comment: Um, square brackets for the sub-query?????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Apex you retrieve the user by using `:APP_USER`. This bind variable contains the value used by the user to log in to the application (the value from `:P101_USERNAME` on the login page thus).

If you need an actual ID or any other related info pertaining to the user you should create some application items to store that info. In the post-authentication procedure of the authentication scheme you can then retrieve the values into the application items, based on the used login name.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your intention, the proper SQL would be:

```
SELECT m.module_code, m.module_name, m.lecturer_code, 
      m.module_number_assessments, m.module_moderator
FROM module m JOIN
     lecturer l 
     ON m.lecturer_code = l.lecturer_code
WHERE l.lecturer_code = UserInfo.getUserId();
```

`UserInfo.getUserId()` is not a standard part of Oracle (as far as I know).  You can use `USER` or a similar function to get the user id inside the database.  A general function for getting system information is `SYS_CONTEXT()`, which is documented [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions184.htm#SQLRF06117).  You probably want "SYSTEM_USER":  `SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'SESSION_USER')`.

In your case, you might just want `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT m.*
FROM module m
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM lecture l
              WHERE m.lecturer_code = l.lecturer_code AND
                    l.lecturer_code = UserInfo.getUserId()
             );
```

Neither of these address the issue that `UserInfo.getUserId()` is not understood by Oracle.

Comment: I think your syntax is correct, and a lot cleaner than mine. I believe you're right, I think APEX isn't allowing me to use the UserInfo.getUserID(). Any good documentation I could use for the USER function?

Comment: The syntax up till the `SYS_CONTEXT` is working, but I can't get the actual `SYS_CONTEXT` section working correctly. I couldn't find "SYSTEM_USER" in the `SYS_CONTEXT` documentation.

I've attempted `SYS_CONTEXT('SYSTEM_USER', 'USER')`, `SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'SESSION_USER')` and `SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'SESSION_USERID')`

Comment: @AdamMcquiff . . . Does just `USER` work?  (i.e. `l.lecturer_code = USER`)

Comment: Just tried, and also shows no record. I have created a custom login table, could this be part of the error?

Comment: @AdamMcquiff . . . That is probably the problem.  You need to put in whatever logic you have for getting the current user, given your custom table.

Answer (score 1):

Create a page process with package as:

```
  declare
        v varchar2(255) := null;
        c owa_cookie.cookie;
    begin
       c := owa_cookie.get('LOGIN_USERNAME_COOKIE');
       :P1_USERNAME := c.vals(1);
    exception when others then null;
    end;
```

[Reference](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_easy_html_db_owa_cookie.htm)

Based upon the above procedure for getting user name you can write your query like:

```
SELECT m.module_code, m.module_name, m.lecturer_code, 
m.module_number_assessments, m.module_moderator FROM module m, lecturer l 
WHERE m.lecturer_code = (Select l.lecturer_code from lecturer l where 
l.lecturer_code = :P1_USERNAME);
```

> Make appropriate change in your database table for lecture code to be
>   comparable with username

Answer (score 0):

As i know there isnt any code similar to UserInfo.getUserId() in apex

in my codes i am using apex cookie for getting the username of loggined user then for finding id i am using a code similar to below in parenthesis 
for adapting you may use as below

```
l.lecturer_code = (select USER_ID from USERS_TABLE where USER_USERNAME=apex_authentication.get_login_username_cookie)
```